# Error al insertar registro: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Estoy atascado con este problema que dice que estoy tratando de insertar o actualizar un número incorrecto de valores en una tabla en la base de datos y no logro encontrar en error o cómo solucionarlo.

Acá les dejo el código de la función:

```
function updateTotal($orderID) {
    global $sqlconnection;

    $query = "
        UPDATE tbl_order O
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT OD.orderID, SUM(OD.quantity*MI.price) AS total
            FROM tbl_orderdetail OD 
            LEFT JOIN tbl_menuitem MI
            ON OD.itemID = MI.itemID
            LEFT JOIN tbl_menu M 
            ON MI.menuID = M.menuID
            WHERE OD.orderID = ".$orderID."
        ) x
        ON O.orderID = x.orderID
        SET O.total = x.total
        WHERE O.orderID = ".$orderID."
    ";

    if ($sqlconnection->query($query) === TRUE) {
        echo "updated.";
    } else {
        //handle error
        echo "something wrong";
        echo $sqlconnection->error;
    }
```

Si les sirve de ayuda puedo publicar las tablas que hacen referencia al código para que la puedan revisar y ayudarme si pueden a encontrar el error.

Acá les dejo las estructuras de las tablas con los valores a las cual hago la llamada para ver si pueden revisarlas:

**Tabla `tbl_order`:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_order` (
  `orderID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` text NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
  `order_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Tabla `tbl_orderdetail`:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_orderdetail` (
  `orderID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `orderDetailID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `itemID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Tabla `tbl_menuitem`:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_menuitem` (
  `itemID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `menuID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `menuItemName` text NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Tabla `tbl_menu`:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_menu` (
  `menuID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `menuName` varchar(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

---

Acá está el código del botón al cual llamo cuando hace la llamada:

```
    function insertOrderQuery($orderID) {
        global $sqlconnection;
        $addOrderQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_order (orderID ,status ,order_date ,total) VALUES ('{$orderID}' ,'waiting' ,CURDATE() )";
        if ($sqlconnection->query($addOrderQuery) == TRUE) {
                echo "inserted.";
            } 

        else {
                //handle
                /*echo "somethingwrong";*/
                echo $sqlconnection->error;
                /*echo "<script>console.log('$addOrderQuery')</script>";*/
                header("Location: index.php");

        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que esa es la consulta SQL que te falla? Teóricamente es correcta. ¿Has depurado el valor del parámetro de la llamada a la función?. Por otro lado, tu código puede sufrir los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyección_SQL). ¿Por qué no usas consultas preparadas o alguna función de escapado? Y, por último, la consulta SQL puede simplificarse enormemente. Te preparo un gist para mostrarte cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Te he creado un gist con la optimización de la consulta SQL: [https://gist.github.com/ojgarciab/a66be8c7408df23c9d996647ca8cafd5](https://gist.github.com/ojgarciab/a66be8c7408df23c9d996647ca8cafd5). Podrás ver que he quitado un `LEFT JOIN` innecesario en la subconsulta y he usado una asignación directa en vez de otro `LEFT JOIN` más en la consulta principal. Además, el `WHERE` interior depende de `O.orderID`, en vez de tener que repetir por segunda vez el valor en la consulta SQL. PD: Si usas `EXPLAIN` podrás ver que las relaciones no están correctamente optimizadas usando índices.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ahora estoy haciendo los arreglos a esa parte del codigo! Si el error no se muestra en los llamados anteriormente puede ser la funcion que hace que ejecute esa funcion? en simples palabras el boton que hace el llamado y la comparacion de cada elemento de las tablas? edito la pregunta y pongo esas llamadas en ella! desde ya muchas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: ¡Ahora sí que hay un error SQL! :D redactando respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a esta consulta SQL:

```
<?php
$addOrderQuery = "
    INSERT INTO tbl_order (
        orderID,
        status,
        order_date,
        total
    ) VALUES (
        '{$orderID}',
        'waiting',
        CURDATE()
    )
";
```

Como puedes ver estás definiendo cuatro campos (`orderID`, `status`, `order_date`, `total`) y, sin embargo, estás asignando tres valores para ellos (`$orderID`, `waiting` y `CURDATE()`). Parece que te falta definir el valor del campo `total`.

---

Tu código puede sufrir los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Te recomiendo encarecidamente que uses consultas preparadas o funciones de escapado de cadenas y que **NUNCA** concatenes cadenas de caracteres que estén fuera de tu control a las consultas SQL.

Una manera rápida de implementar consultas preparadas en tu código sería:

```
<?php
function insertOrderQuery($orderID) {
    global $sqlconnection;
    $addOrderQuery = $sqlconnection->prepare("
        INSERT INTO tbl_order (
            orderID,
            status,
            order_date,
            total
        ) VALUES (
            ?,
            'waiting',
            CURDATE(),
            0
        )
    ");
    if (false === $addOrderQuery) {
        die(htmlspecialchars($sqlconnection->error));
    }
    $addOrderQuery->bind_param("i", $orderID);
    if (true === $addOrderQuery->execute()) {
        echo "inserted.";
    } else {
        //handle
        echo htmlspecialchars($addOrderQuery->error);
        //header("Location: index.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: De verdad gracias he estado 3 dias con este problema revisando todo y era que solo me faltaba agregarle el valor a total! Muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo y por tu ayuda

Comment: Un placer y, por favor, tómate en serio mi consejo de usar consultas preparadas. La seguridad y robustez del código debe implementarse desde sus cimientos y no arreglarse en una segunda fase del desarrollo. ¡Suerte con tu aplicación!

Comment: Ahora me voy a meter a fondo a implementar de llleno las consultas preparadas! Muchas gracias.

Comment: Un último consejo: no uses variables globales (`$sqlconnection`). Deberías usar un [patrón de diseño singleton](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton), recomendablemente junto con un cargador automático de clases como el que usa `composer`, con el que puedas obtener la conexión mysqli desde cualquier punto de tu aplicación mediante la llamada al método estático `$sqlconnection = MiMysqli.getInstance();`. De este modo el código que establece la conexión al servidor MySQL solo se cargará y ejecutará si tu aplicación tiene la necesidad de realizar una consulta SQL.